# Reshaping 12 channels to 3 channel Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How to reshape images input of **12** channels input, to **3** channels input images? From `256, 256, 12` to  3 channels input `xxx,xxx,3`. I have tried

```
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1024,1024,3), input_shape=(256,256,12))
```

but it doesn't work. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Add your model code definition. Do you want to do this via a layer? Where this 12 channels image come from? I think you want to resize input image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `512, 512, 3`, i.e.,  `tf.keras.layers.Reshape((512, 512, 3), input_shape=(256, 256, 12))`.

- `256*256*12 = 786432`
- `1024*1024*3 = 3145728`, therefore `Reshape` won't work.

but

- `256*256*12 = 512*512*3`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, realize cant upvote yet, but already solved my problem